Unexplained difference in results for nested lists of hidden layers
I've built a custom Tensorflow model via the Subclassing API. The model has 3 dense MLPs in parallel (4 hidden layers each) and one output per MLP. They are not connected in any way. I know that I should just build 3 separate models, but I wanted to try something new.
I am creating my hidden layers as a nested list, i.e. a list of MLPs, each containing another list of hidden layers. My problem seems to arise in how I create this nested list as shown below:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # units is a list of integers denoting the number of units per layer
    # activation is a list of str denoting the activation function of each layer
    # nMLP is the number of parallel MLPs

    # Create layers
    self.units = [5,5,5,5]
    self.activation = ['relu','relu','relu','relu']
    self.nlayer = len(self.units)
    self.nMLP = 3

    # DOES NOT WORK #
    # self.layer_hidden = [
    #     [
    #         [] for _ in range(self.nlayer)
    #     ] for _ in range(self.nMLP)
    # ]
    # for iMLP in range(self.nMLP):
    #     for ilayer, (nunits, act) in enumerate(zip(self.units, self.activation)):
    #         self.layer_hidden[iMLP][ilayer] = Dense(units=nunits, activation=act)

    # WORKS #
    self.layer_hidden = [
        [
            Dense(units=nunits, activation=act) for nunits, act in zip(self.units, self.activation)
        ] for _ in range(self.nMLP)
    ]

I can create the nested list either with nested loops or with nested list comprehension. Both appear equivalent to me and when I query the model after being built, they both have the same shape, e.g. (nMLP, nlayer). They also aren't copies of references pointing to the same object, so each element is unique.
However when training, the nested loop approach seems to result in very high errors and does not converge, while the nested list comprehension approach converges just fine and is able to predict the data accurately. I isolated it to this piece of code simply by commenting out either section and retraining the model.
Both approaches to dynamically creating layers are valid for a single list of layers (not nested). But for some reason, nesting results in this problem. Other posts on dynamically creating layers also recommend either approaches: How to create a dynamic number of layers in Tensorflow?
I implemented the build_graph() method of: How do I plot a Keras/Tensorflow subclassing API model? to visualise my graph structure and both are equivalent and correct.
Is there something I'm missing?
